# Installed mongoDB server but mongoimport not found

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have installed mongoDB on a Amazon Linux instance following this guide http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/platforms/amazon-ec2/. At this point I have to execute `mongoimport` command but it is not found. Do you know how can I install it? Why doesn't this one is not contained into the mongodb-server and mongodb-shell packages?

Comment: Should be in a mongodb*tools package.

Comment: just found it thank you

Comment: @TeTeT when you say mongodb*tools package, what do you mean? is it a yum package? I can't find mongoimport, mongoexport or mongodump, etc.

Comment: @Hans Hard to tell what the package is actually called, glad you found it for your distribution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding this answer for reference to others

yum install mongodb-org-tools

Comment: No package mongodb-org-tools available is what I get when running this on amazon linux

Answer (score 6):

For people on Arch and Manjaro, the package you need is `mongodb-tools`

Comment: this still seems like the right answer in 2020, worked for me today to get `mongoimport` working and it succeeded

Answer (score 5):

mongoimport command is made available by 2 packages

`mongodb-org-tools
mongo-tools`

Hence installing either of these 2 packages should suffice

*Fedora*

`dnf install`

*Ubuntu*

`apt-get install`

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 16.04:

```
sudo apt install mongodb-clients
```